# How to exclude stocks based on technicals on python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, finance

I have a code that gives me the technicals of stocks from yahoo, no problem with that, but I am trying to get the program to not print stocks if they do not meet requirements, for example, if revenue is not greater than 100B.

I have tried an if statement at various parts of this code, none seem to work.

```
    technicals = {}
    try:
        url = ('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s='+stock)
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        tables = soup.findAll('table', {"class" : 'table-qsp-stats'})    # Found using page inspection
        for table in tables:
            table_body = table.find('tbody')
            rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

            for row in rows:
                col_name = row.find_all('span')                            # Use span to avoid supscripts
                col_name = [cell.text.strip() for cell in col_name]
                col_val = row.find_all('td')
                col_val = [cell.text.strip() for cell in col_val]
                technicals[col_name[0]] = col_val[1]                    # col_val[0] is the name cell (with subscript)
        return technicals
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed, exception: ', str(e))



def scrape(stock_list, interested, technicals):
    for each_stock in stock_list:
        technicals = scrape_yahoo(each_stock)
        if int('Revenue') > 100000000000:
            print(each_stock)
            for ind in interested:
                print(ind + ": "+ technicals[ind])
            print("------")
            time.sleep(1)                                                    # Use delay to avoid getting flagged as bot
    return technicals

def main():
    stock_list = ['aapl', 'tsla', 'ge']
    interested = ['Market Cap (intraday)', 'Return on Equity', 'Revenue', 'Quarterly Revenue Growth']
    technicals = {}
    tech = scrape(stock_list, interested, technicals)
    print(tech)


main()
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Revenue'

Comment: you are trying to conver string to int if `int('Revenue')`, Did you define the Revenue value ?

Comment: add sample value for technical

Answer (score 0):

i assume that `technical` variable is a `dict` and it has `Revenue` key. 
you should change from

```
if  int('Revenue')
```

to

```
if  int(technical.get('Revenue',0))
```

Comment: I changed it, and now it says "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '258.49B'". Also, just curious, what does the zero signify in your code?

Comment: 258.48B. What does the zero signify in the .get function?

Comment: in get you can specify default value, refer : https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/not_using_get_to_return_a_default_value_from_a_dictionary.html#use-dict-get-key-default-to-assign-default-values

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def scrape_yahoo(stock):
    technicals = {}
    try:
        url = ('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s= ' +stock)
        page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        tables = soup.findAll('table', {"class" : 'table-qsp-stats'})    # Found using page inspection
        for table in tables:
            table_body = table.find('tbody')
            rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

            for row in rows:
                col_name = row.find_all('span')                            # Use span to avoid supscripts
                col_name = [cell.text.strip() for cell in col_name]
                col_val = row.find_all('td')
                col_val = [cell.text.strip() for cell in col_val]
                technicals[col_name[0]] = col_val[1]                    # col_val[0] is the name cell (with subscript)
        return technicals
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed, exception: ', str(e))


def scrape(stock_list, interested, technicals):
    for each_stock in stock_list:
        technicals = scrape_yahoo(each_stock)

        if (float(technicals.get('Revenue',0).replace("B","")))*1000000000 > 100000000000:
            print(each_stock)
            for ind in interested:
                print(ind + ": "+ technicals[ind])
            print("------")
            time.sleep(1)                                                    # Use delay to avoid getting flagged as bot
    return technicals

def main():
    stock_list = ['aapl', 'tsla', 'ge']
    interested = ['Market Cap (intraday)', 'Return on Equity', 'Revenue', 'Quarterly Revenue Growth']
    technicals = {}
    tech = scrape(stock_list, interested, technicals)
    print(tech)


main()
```

Comment: I added this code "(float(technicals.get('Price/Book (mrq)',0).replace('N/A', "")))< 3:". It is now giving me the following error:AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'